# Div resizing not working correctly

Tags: css, html, resize

I am writing some css code for a school website that looks like this

```
body{
background:#000099 url('repeat.png') repeat-x;
margin-bottom:50px;
}



div.wsite-theme{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border-top:5px solid #AAAAAA;
}

div.wsite-header{
background:#DDDDDD;
border-radius:5px;
}

#wrapper {
width:960px;
margin:0pt auto;
}

#content{
width:850px;
min-height:694px;
position:absolute;
left:98px;
top:150px;
}

#content-main{
width:100%;
min-height:594px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
}

#navigation{
min-height:1px;
position:absolute;
left:98px;
top:90px;
line-height:2px;
padding:10px 10px;
width:850px;
}

#header{
width:850px;
height:150px;
position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:98px;
}

#footer{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:#DDDDDD;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
border-top:5px solid #AAAAAA;
}
```

with html that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{title}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main-style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header" class="wsite-header">
<h1 class="title1">{title}</h1>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
{menu}
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="content-main" class="wsite-theme">
{content}
</div>
<div id="footer">
{footer}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(ignore content in curly bracers. it for the website editor our school makes us use)
So when i go on my page and type in the content it re-sizes and goes behind the footer . However what i intend for it to do is push the footer down as it re-sizes to fit the content. Earlier it was behaving this way, so what am i doing wrong?

EDIT: i guess i wasn't clear enough at first,i want the parent `#content` div to resize with the content main div so the footer is pushed down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using absolute position at all? Remove all of the `position: absolute` from all of your DIVs they are not necessary. Position them using margins instead and you will not have a problem with the DIVs changing size.

As Mathew mentioned, when you use the `position: absolute` property, it takes that element out of the flow of the document so it will not affect the elements around it. All of your DIVs are in the order you want them displayed, there is no need for absolute positioning on any of them.

Just took out the positioning and messed with the padding of the wrapper to get the same thing you are trying - http://jsfiddle.net/n3Xqx/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `position: absolute;`, it takes things out of the regular document flow.

EDIT: If you need to give more vertical spacing between the header/footer/content areas, then use `margin`

Comment: How can i position it the same without absolute though?

Answer (score 0):

Add position relative to the wrapper.
Replace position absolute to relative for content and footer.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0pt auto;
    position: relative;
}    
#content {
    width: 850px;
    min-height: 694px;
    left: 98px;
    top: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
#content-main {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 594px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-top: 5px solid #AAAAAA;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: that makes the footer above the content. i want it at the bottom and it still does not fix my problem which is that `#content` does not expand when `#content-main` does. Also this makes my header out of place and my nav bar

Comment: I forgot delete the position absolute on footer and content thats why the footer was on top of the contents. I have updated the the css above

Comment: Add position relative at #content-main also instead of absolute then It will work. See on Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tQeDz/